# Need help to understand the billing terms/parameters of Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a azure storage account in V1. Now I am confused about shifting to V2. My system is accessing, moving and deleting the blob files very frequently. So, if I move to V2, I have to keep it Hot tier.

My system is processing around 1000 blob files daily and their total size will be around 1 GB. So at the end of the month, total 30000 files will be created in my system. all 30000 will be processed and moved to different blob folder (Deleted from current and created in other). Means 30 GB blob file will be created and moved.

To calculate the price of this scenario I have used following link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?&OCID=AID719810_SEM_ha1Od3sE&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CMTolaWp3OECFQLtjgodO7oBpQ

Calculation of billing in V1 (RA-GRS) is easy. it contains only two parameters:

1. Capacity
2. Storage transactions

So I selected 30GB as Capacity and 60000 (30000 created and 30000 move) Storage transactions. It costs me US$ 23.43

I want to calculate the same thing for V2 (RA-GRS and Hot Tier). But there are so many parameters:

1. Capacity
2. Write Operations
3. List and Create Container Operations
4. Read operations
5. All other operations
6. Data retrieval
7. Data write
8. Geo-replication data transfer

I am confused about in which field I should fill what value?

Please help me to understand these parameters/fields of storage account V2 billing.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because billing questions are off topic here. contact azure billing support, its free.